# Resources path in C# Window Form application?

Tags: c#, path

having problems in my project with path to Resources folder. This is a short part from my code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.loader;

Random rnd = new Random();
int Num1 = rnd.Next(1, 50);

labelRandom1.Text = Num1.ToString();

var path = @"C:\Users\Palan\Desktop\Slot\Automat\Automat\Resources\";
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path + "picture" + Num1.ToString() + ".bmp");
```

In pictureBox1 is image called "loader" which is located in Resources. Then random number between 1 & 50 is generated, then the number is displayed in labelRandom1 as Text and after that the picture in pictureBox1 with name "picture(generated number).bmp" is shown - (e.g. picture40.bmp when the number 40 is generated).

I need help with creating the path to the Resources file, because "Properties.Resources("picture" + Num1);" is not working and path to the file in "@"C:\Users\Palan\Desktop\Slot\Automat\Automat\Resources\";" works only on my own computer.

Comment: Just look at the Resources.Designer.cs file and you'll instantly see how to use ResourceManager.GetObject().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have some images with name **picture1**, **picture2**... as Resources and you need a path to them.Well that's pretty simple.

```
 string imagePath=picture{0};
 pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.loader;

 Random rnd = new Random();
 int Num1 = rnd.Next(1, 50);

 labelRandom1.Text = Num1.ToString();

 ResourceManager resMan=Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
 pictureBox1.Image = (Image)resMan.GetObject((string.Format(imagePath,Num1));
```

This should work for you.And take a look [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61g0tfol6m2l3nb/Image%20Resource.zip) if there's still any problem.

Comment: @user3078537 Try the updated solution and take a look at sample project.